# How to pass Array Variable (Blade Template) to CodeIgniter View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, laravel-blade

I'm working with https://github.com/cntaoyu/CI-Blade framework and my controller is :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $data['student'] = array('rollno' => '1','name' => 'Joyy');
        $this->blade->view('welcome_message', $data['student']);
    }
}
```

**VIEW FILE**

```
{{$name}} // this prints Joyy

@foreach($student as $users) //student or data, both dont work
    <h2>{{ $users }}</h2>                                                                
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass variable in controller and use assignee name of variable in view file.
Consider below example

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function index()
        {
            $data['student'] = array('rollno' => '1','name' => 'Joyy');
            $this->blade->view('welcome_message', ['students' => $data['student']]);
        }
    }
```

VIEW FILE

```
{{$name}} // this prints Joyy

@foreach($students as $student) //student or data, both dont work
    <h2>{{ $student }}</h2>                                                                
@endforeach
```